# Running threads in Spark DataFrame foreachPartition()

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use multiple threads inside `foreachPartition()`, which works great for me except for when the underlying iterator is `TungstenAggregationIterator`. Here is a minimal code snippet to reproduce:

```
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
    import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

    object Reproduce extends App {

      val sc = new SparkContext("local", "reproduce")
      val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

      import sqlContext.implicits._

      val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(1)).toDF("number").groupBy("number").count()

      df.foreachPartition { iterator =>
        val f = Future(iterator.toVector)
        Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
      }
    }
```

When I run this, I get:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.next(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:751)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.next(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:84)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
```

I believe I actually understand why this happens - `TungstenAggregationIterator` uses a `ThreadLocal` variable that returns `null` when called from a thread other than the original thread that got the iterator from Spark. From examining the code, this does not appear to differ between recent Spark versions.

However, this limitation is specific to `TungstenAggregationIterator`, and not documented, as far as I'm aware.

Is there a way to work around this limitation of `TungstenAggregationIterator`? Any relevant documentation? I have a workaround for this, but it's quite hacky and unnecessarily reduces runtime performance.